# Setting up a router as a DNS server only

Tags: router, dns, dd-wrt

I have a Linksys WRT54GL router that I don't need anymore, since I had to buy a 3G capable router (Dovado 3GN). As I only have a 3G connection at home, I want to optimize it as much as possible.

I want to setup a caching DNS server, including some blacklisting of ad domains. The router currently runs the DD-WRT firmware.

Is it possible to use this router as an ordinary computer, running only a DNS server, disabling all other features such as DHCP, WLAN, etc? Connecting it to my other router, should I simply run a cable into the WAN-port of the Linksys router?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic idea is sound.  Yes you can setup an older router to perform services for your network.  I would use OpenWRT, connect a LAN port of the router to another switch on  your network and I would setup [DNSMasq](http://wiki.openwrt.org/oldwiki/openwrtdocs/dnsmasq) for handling the various DNS tasks you identified.

Comment: I did what you suggested and it works fine. dnsmasq seems to cache requests on the router and ad blocking works for all of my clients and indeed speeds up browsing.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [OpenWRT](http://openwrt.org/) or [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index), both provide a lot more functionality than the default firmware and should be able to do what you need.

OpenWRT will essentially turn the router into a small linux box and from there you can go to wherever you need.

Comment: Thanks, but I stated in my comment that I already run DD-WRT. I will probably switch to OpenWRT though, since I have previously setup DNS servers in Linux.